# How to add UICollectionView Header

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I wish to add a label to my UICollectionView programmatically, and have used the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind and referenceSizeForHeaderInSection to set it up, however for some reason when I setup my views it is still placing it inside the first row of my CollectionView instead of the created header. [As you can see in this screenshot, "Today" is in the first cell, instead of the header I created for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPSbE.png)

```
class TvController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

private let cellId = "cellId"
private let headerId = "headerId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "TV"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

    collectionView?.register(TvCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.register(Header.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: headerId)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}

//Row for each TV show
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 120)
}

//Today's date header
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! Header

    return header
}

//Today's date header
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 60)
}
}
```

Here is the Header class

```
class Header: UICollectionViewCell  {

override init(frame: CGRect)    {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupHeaderViews()
}

let dateLabel: UILabel = {
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = "Today"
    title.textColor = .gray
    title.backgroundColor = .black
    title.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat", size: 17)
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return title
}()

func setupHeaderViews()   {
    addSubview(dateLabel)

    dateLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    dateLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    dateLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong method to register your header.
You're also dequeuing using the wrong method. Since you're registering your header as a forSupplementaryViewOfKind -- You have to use deque the header using **'dequeueReusableSupplementaryView'** method instead of **'dequeueReusableCell'**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView?.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:
       UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
  }


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind:
    String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier:
            headerId, for: indexPath) as! Header
        return header
}
```

Comment: Thanks antwash for your answer, it seems now I get an error in the build. It states: 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier headerId - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Do you know what I would have to do now?

Comment: Check out the edit, it shows what you should have in the viewDidLoad and your viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind methods. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Ahhh I see, sorry about that, I'm still learning :) Thanks so much for your help! I understand now.

Comment: No worries, I'm 5 months into ios and learning more and more every day =]

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderId", for: indexPath) as! HeaderClassname
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            //Your Code Here
        } else {
        }
        return headerView

    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }

    return headerView
}
```